# Google sheets apps script - Unable to capture cell click event

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to use use a cell click event (or its equivalent) to copy the current cell value, append a calculated value to it and then write the result to a different cell located on a different sheet. The contents of the origin cell are defined using `RichTextValueBuilder.setLinkUrl`. Class `RichTextValue` is able to view the contents of the cell, however the click event on the cell of interest if never triggered.

In testing, my approach has been demonstrated to work. However, when I move the code into an event such as `onSelectionChange`, nothing happens. Ever. Following is sample:

Expected Results:
Target cell on a different sheet is selected and populated with intended content.

Following is sample:

```
 function onSelectionChange(e)
    {
      var activeMrmSheets = e.parameter.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Problem is here: e is never defined.
      var patientSheet = activeMrmSheets.getSheetByName('Example1');
      var cellContents = patientSheet.getRange('B8');
      var cellTextValue = cellContents.getRichTextValue(); //
      var requiredInfo = cellTextValue.getText(); //First reason for this method.
      var processedInfo = ProcessorFunction(requiredInfo);
      FunctionThatWritesToTargetSheet(processedInfo); //Second reason for this method.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Been offline; let me look at your response.

Comment: `when I move the code into an event such as onSelectionChange, nothing happens` Just to clarify: the function needs a trigger. Have you created an installable `onEdit` trigger for `onSelectionChange`?